# How do I calculate the size of a react component before rendering?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on a react component that renders chips of different sizes based on different data. I don't want the area where the chips are rendered to exceed 2 rows and if they do exceed 2 rows then hide the rest of the chips and render an icon for to click on for more info. Something similar tot he following:
[image]

The problem is I don't know how long the text in the chips can be so I don't know when to hide the additional chips and render the info icon.

I don't need a complete solution I'm looking for some guidance on how this could be achievable in react because I don't think I can get the measurements of the chip component before they are rendered, right?

Here is a little jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/54yc9kuv/16/

```
const TodoApp = () => {

  return (
    <div><Parent /></div>
  ); 
}

const Parent = () => {
    return (
    <div className="parentComp">
      <ChildOne />
      <ChildTwo />
    </div>
  );
}

const ChildOne = () => {
    return (<div className="childOne">Some random descriptions about the items</div>)
}

const ChildTwo = () => {
    const chipData = ["Apples & Kiwis", "Orange", "Grape", "Peach", "Mangoes, Cherry & Peach"]; 
    return (
  <div className="childTwo">
    {chipData.map(name => (
    <Chip key={name} name={name} />
        ))}
  </div>)
}

const Chip = ({name}) => {
    return <div className="chip">{name}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

In the example above I don't want "Mangoes, Cherry & Peach" to render instead have some icon render that you can click on if the chips start exceeded two rows.

Comment: see: [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)

Comment: This might also help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

Comment: Combine the two and you're well on your way.

Comment: @pilchard If I'm not mistaken though that gives me measurement after render, no? I need to figure out if that size makes sense before it's actually rendered.

Comment: never mind, I was reading the docs wrong. I think this might be a good place to start.